# I'm having trouble changing the link of a WebView in my Android app

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I am facing a problem when changing the link from
https://massoq.com
to
http://massoq.com
Remove the s
I export the application and try it. I encounter a message stating that there is no internet. Make sure the internet is connected
What is the correct way to change the link

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    private val website_url = "https://massoq.com"
    private var dial: AlertDialog? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webview.setListener(this, this)
        webview.setMixedContentAllowed(false)
        webview.loadUrl(website_url)

        swipe.setOnRefreshListener {
            webview.reload()
          //  Toast.makeText(this,"refreshing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: HTTP (plain text) connections are disallowed for Android apps by default. If you want to allow HTTP for one URL you have to create a network security config file and allow http for one or more domains: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config